# Read csv for file first column and search for directory on filesystem identical to the values in first column using UNIX shell script

Tags: linux, shell, csv

I am having the CSV file with multiple columns in it.

But I want to read this CSV file using **LINUX shell script** only for the **first column** with header named **Key**, having values under it

```
TST-1, TST-2, ..., PROJ-1,PROJ-2,....
```

Picking first value - TST-1, I need to check whether there is any sub-directory named **TST-1** under the directory /opt/usr/tomcat/home/data/attachments/. If yes then I want to move this directory to the backup deive. Similarly for the remaining values under the first column **Key**

I can move the directories without using the CSV file by using the **find** and **rsync** commands in Linux but the data I got is stored in CSV file and I am quite unfamiliar with reading the CSV using Linux shell script

Can anybody help me with this!

Thanks,
Narendra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
value=$(awk -F, 'NR>2{print $1}' file.csv)
if [ -d "/opt/usr/tomcat/home/data/attachments/$value" ]; then
    mv "/opt/usr/tomcat/home/data/attachments/$value" backup_drive
fi
```

Note : if your `CSV` is simple, it's ok, but if it haves some values like `"aa,aa", xxx, zzz`, better use `perl`, `ruby` or `python` with a *CSV parser*

Comment: Thanks! with your help I was able to read the CSV file. But with the command value=$(awk -F, 'NR>1 {print $1}' test.csv), when I echo the o/p for value, I get continuous o/p -> "TST-1" "TST-2". I am not able to segreggate the value "TST-1" from "TST-2" and so on.... Using this single entries "TST-1", "TST-2",.... I check whether the directories named TST-1, TST-2,... are present and move them using command - find /opt/XXXX/tomcat/data/attachments -name $value -exec rsync -avR --remove-sent-files {} /path/to/backup/drive/ \; 

Any help much appreciated!